# Handler: передача между классами

Tags: android, массивы, передача-данных

Есть 2 класса.

Первый:

```
public class List extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2;
    Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter1)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);
                    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И второй:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Каким образом через `Handler` можно передать название адаптера (adapter1, adapter2) из первого класса во второй?

Comment: как эти 2 класса связаны между собой?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Боюсь никак, `Handler` не предназначен для передачи данных между компонентами. Если Вам нужно передать что то из фрагмента в содержащую его активити, то просто создайте в активити публичный метод и вызовите его из фрагмента как то так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void doSomething(Object data) {
        // todo
    }
}

public class List extends ListFragment {
    public void passSomethingToActivity(Object data) {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).doSomething(data);
    }
}
```

---

Но лучше сохранять и восстанавливать состояние как то так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onBackPressed() {
        List fragment = (List) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null || !fragment.onBackPressed()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

public class List extends ListFragment {
    private Stack<Integer> backStack = new Stack();

    private void pushAdapterByNum(int num) {
        backStack.push(num);
        setAdapterByNum(num);
    }

    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        if (backStack.empty()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            setAdapterByNum(backStack.pop());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы из класса List название адаптера (adapter1, adapter2) передавалось в метод onBackPressed(), объявленный в MainActicty. Метод onBackPressed() получает название адаптера и выполняет соответствующие действия.

Не подскажете, каким образом можно реализовать такой функционал? Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: В вашем случае архитектурно более правильным будет не передавать в активити название адаптера, а сделать во фрагменте метод `public boolean onBackPressed()` в котором реализовать всю логику возвращения старого адаптера, и который вы будете дергать из `onBackPressed()` активити.

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, но очень прошу дать ответ на последний вопрос. Как именно в public boolean onBackPressed() можно реализовать логику возвращения предыдущего адаптера? Пожалуйста, поделитесь хотя бы самым простым примером, а дальше, если что, я сам додумаю.

Comment: Добавил в ответ